# Custom fonts in a CustomTheme library

Tags: wpf, xaml

I cannot get a custom font to work in a library theme.

This is something super simple but currently driving me insane.  I created a Theme library for my app's styles, colors, fonts etc...

I have a style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/MyThemes;component/Fonts/#Roboto"/>
</Style>
```

Ignoring the custom font the style works correctly.  If I change the font to a built-in Windows font it works perfectly.  However when I set the custom font it doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do using this way

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
   <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="/MyThemes;component/Fonts/#Roboto"/>
</Style>
```

Also make sure that you properly referenced your font in theme and marked it as resource. There are also some helpful details in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications)